# Request-Response Vs Duplex WCF Message Exchange Pattern

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

What is the main difference between Request-Response and Duplex in WCF Message Exchange Pattern?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main difference is that, after the client establishes a channel to the service, the service can call the client independently at any time. In Request-Response the service only communicates back after receiving a Request from the client. So by using duplex you receive an event-like behavior from the client perspective. Obviously such enhancement requires a Session to be maintained (instance mode `PerSession` on the service). You can read more on the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx).